# How to find second value inside a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I list the names of all band members with the same last name?

The column has values like this

```
band_NAME
-------------------
Carla Thomas
Stephen E. Rice
Cynthia P. Tree
Richard Anthony Paul
Ann Frances Smith
Lorace Black
Timothy Adam Paul
```

I know we would have to use `instr` and `substr`. I just don't get how we would determine the position.

I know the basic format is going to be like

```
SELECT band_NAME 
FROM TABLE 
where substr(band_name, ?, instr( ) IN 
    (select substr(band_name, ?, instr( )-1)  
     from table 
     group by SUBSTR(band_NAME , ?, INSTR( )-1 ) 
     HAVING COUNT(* ) > 1 );
```

But what goes in the question marks and inside the `instr`?

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: How is this supposed to work? In 'Jerry Lee Lewis' the first name is 'Jerry Lee', the surname 'Lewis', so you split first and surname at the last blank. In 'Gabriel García Márquez' the first name is 'Gabriel' and the surname is 'García Márquez', i.e. you split at the first blank. There also exist names like 'Juan Luis García Perales' where it's neither the first nor the last blank that separates first and surname. Then think about Chinese names, where the surname comes first.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I don't understand how to split it. Some of the names listed above have a middle initial so that could be split after the period but as for others with three names, I have no idea how I would do it. Just need to figure out a way to find a match on the last names and display them

Comment: What I am saying is that you cannot derive what is first name and what is surname from the complete name only. You'd have to have more information. A dictionary of first and surnames maybe. (And even then, "Paul" can both be a first name and a surname). Maybe you are fine with some compromise. But it's up to you then to define the rules that you'd be fine with.

Comment: Well there's a couple of more columns associated but none of them determine what's the first name/last name...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your delimiter between first and last name is a single space. More spaces in the string are a part of last name. Thus, you probably want to search for the first space character.

Return position of the first occurence of substring with [`instr(str, substr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr).

Then, use [`substring(str, pos)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to return the substring starting at a given position (feed by instr function).

```
SELECT substring(band_name, instr(band_name, ' '))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I tried this attempt before I posted the question but it doesn't work properly unforunately :(

Comment: @Bob: This doesn't tell Consider Me anything. What does "it doesn't work properly unfortunately" mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete beginner at this. When I tried the code above it said "invalid"..

Comment: @Bob, this doesn't let me reproduce anything. Attach desired result in your question . . . Also, full code and error you've been trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.band_NAME
FROM TABLE t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE t2
 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.band_name, ' ', - 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.band_name, ' ', - 1)
WHERE t1.band_name <> t2.band_name
```

And this like your pseudocode **MySQL**:

```
SELECT band_NAME FROM TABLE
Where FIND_IN_SET (SUBSTRING_INDEX(band_name, ' ', -1),
 (Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(band_name, ' ', -1) bn
 From TABLE Group by bn
 having Count(bn) > 1
 )
)
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT band_NAME FROM TABLE
Where
 SUBSTRING(band_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', band_NAME) + 1, LEN(band_NAME)) AS [Last Name]
IN
 (Select SUBSTRING(band_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', band_NAME) + 1, LEN(band_NAME)) AS [Last Name]
 From TABLE Group by [Last Name] -- or SUBSTRING(band_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', band_NAME) + 1, LEN(band_NAME)) AS [Last Name]
 having Count(*) > 1
 )
)
```

Additionally I thinks you can benefit from [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) in some way

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine with me, Can you make sure that the parentheses closed correctly ? and you change `TABLE` in the 2 places with your real table name ? @Bob

Comment: with your exact query it says "unexpected end of sql command." Im using sql developer if that makes a difference..? It doesn't recognize "substring index", so I replaced it with substr after adding another parenthesis. Then it says "bn" is an "invalid operator--doesn't exist".

Comment: Oh you tagged your question with `mysql` @Bob

Comment: @Bob sorry I do not have `sql server` so I tried to wrote as I expect, Try the edited answer and let me know

Comment: with the updated code it's saying invalid relational operator. I tried both ways. Sql developer doesn't recognize "len" so I changed that to length. Also changed substring to substr, and charindex to instr. Don't understand why it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 with cte as
(
select band_name, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by SUBSTRING(band_name,CHARINDEX(' ',band_name),LEN(band_name))  order by band_name) as cnt,
        SUBSTRING(band_name,CHARINDEX(' ',band_name),LEN(band_name)) as lastname
from your_table
)
select band_name 
from cte
where lastname in (select lastname from cte where cnt > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

okay,

The best solution is to change your schema and store last name in a separate column.

In the mean time you could get the last name like this,

```
SELECT
            [band_NAME],
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [band_NAME]) > 0
                THEN
                    RIGHT([band_NAME], CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([band_NAME])))
                ELSE
                    [band_NAME]
            END [LastName]
    FROM
            [TABLE]
```

You could then group them like this

```
SELECT
            [LastName],
            COUNT(*)
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                     [band_NAME],
                     CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', [band_NAME]) > 0
                        THEN
                            RIGHT([band_NAME], CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([band_NAME])))
                        ELSE
                            [band_NAME]
                   END [LastName]
                FROM
                   [TABLE]
        ) [TABLEWithLastName]
    GROUP BY
            [LastName];
```